# internet connection on FortiWiFi 60C

Tags: router

I'm trying to change my old router to FortiWiFi 60C 
When I connect 60C to uplink, wan1 receive all setting by DHCP, but there is no internet connecting.
Wan1
ip: 46.x.x.51 255.255.255.255
gw 176.56.55.1

I try to add static route 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 to 176.56.55.1 but no luck
I even update firmware to latest
+My ISP using IPoE, but I clone mac address from my old router.

Any idea what can cause this problem?

Comment: You'll need to contact your ISP as they may have some additional settings... they may not give these to you as you may be required to use their equipment. Worth a try, first, though...

Comment: @big-chris Funny, but ISP phone support don't let me talk to technician ). There are not additional setting, all comes from dchp server

Comment: You may well get the details via DHCP but your modem may also send some additional options to authenticate or your ISP, for example, Sky (UK) use MER. If your ISP can't or won't help then there's very little we can do that won't involve hours of trawling the Internet trying to see if someone else has achieved the same on your ISP...

Comment: Yes it is really small provider and it is only one in my building (. For authenticating they use IPoE (not PPPoE or L2TP) IPoE really popular in Russia and it is not really a standard. Here some info -> **goo.gl/4XTOHa** Also there is no modem, router(mine) to switch(isp) connection. And if I change router, it detects that mac address changed and on computer switch any web page to ISP login&pass page. But only if mac changing.

Comment: I check traffic on link to ISP and there is no outgoing traffic from fortigate, only dhcp and incoming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FortiGate will consider a next-hop or default gateway valid and insert it in the routing table under the following conditions :
DHCP interface : next-hop or default gateway acquired by the DHCP server must be in the same subnet as the interface

http://kb.fortinet.com/kb/viewContent.do?externalId=FD30119&sliceId=1